# how to remove foorterview from listview after pagination is finished in Android?

Tags: android, pagination

I'm getting  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2 when i reached at last page and trying to remove footer view from list-view. Can some one please help me to solve this issue.

Here is code for add footer view to list view .

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_AllPost);
        footer = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.prohressbar, listView, false);
        rLayout = (RelativeLayout) footer.findViewById(R.id.progressRel);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) footer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnLoadMore = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnLoadMore);
        btnLoadMore.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        progressBar.getLayoutParams().height = 130;
        btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is my pagination methods.

```
filter_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String selectedFromList = (filter_list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

                        if (selectedFromList.equals("My Post")) {
                           populate_MyAllPostList(OFFSET);
                            btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            LoginUser_PostLoacalPages();
                        }
                        if (selectedFromList.equals("All Post")) {
                            populateList(OFFSET);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Pegination();

                        }
                        if (selectedFromList.equals("R-Post")) {
                           populate_StarPost(OFFSET);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            R_Post_Pagination();
                        }        }
        });
```

Here is my pagination code.

```
public void LoginUser_PostLoacalPages() {

        listView.removeFooterView(footer);
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int total;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {

                total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

                if (totalItems > 0 && total > 0 && total == totalItems) 
                {
                    if (preLast != total) 
                    {
                        if (pageCount < MyPost_LocalPages) 
                        {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
                            {
                                public void run() {
                                    pageCount++;
                                     int OFFSET_SCROLL = 50;
                                  List<All_Post> allDesc =  dbhelper.getMyAllPost(str_LoginUserId, OFFSET_SCROLL);
                                    for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc) {

                                        descArray.add(all_Post);
                                    }
                                    if (adapter != null) {
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        listView.setSelection(totalItems);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 2500);
                        }
                        preLast = total;

                    }

                    preLast = total;

                    if (pageCount == MyPost_LocalPages)
                    {
                        if (preLast == total)
                        {
                            Log.e("", "pageCount preLast=" + pageCount + " MyPost_LocalPages=" + MyPost_LocalPages);
                            listView.removeFooterView(footer);
                            pageCount = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }




public void R_Post_Pagination()
    {
        listView.removeFooterView(footer);
         btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.addFooterView(footer);

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int total;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {

                total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;

                if (totalItems > 0 && total > 0 && total == totalItems) {
                    if (preLast != total) {
                        if (R_PageCount < R_Post_LocalPages) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    R_PageCount++;


                                    int OFFSET_SCROLL = 50;
                                    List<All_Post> allDesc = dbhelper.getMyAll_StarPost(OFFSET_SCROLL);
                                    for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc) {

                                        descArray.add(all_Post);
                                    }
                                    if (adapter != null) {
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        listView.setSelection(totalItems);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 2500);
                        }
                        preLast = total;

                    }

                    preLast = total;

                    if (R_PageCount == R_Post_LocalPages) {
                        if (preLast == total) 
                        {
                            Log.e("", "pageCount preLast=" + R_PageCount + " R_Post_LocalPages=" + R_Post_LocalPages);
                            listView.removeFooterView(footer);
                            R_PageCount = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is log cat error information.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
            at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3334)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4434)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14242)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15364)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14242)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14234)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14234)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14234)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14234)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15057)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3322)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchDraw(PhoneWindow.java:2845)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15364)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:647)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2824)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14242)
            at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14272)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:267)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
            at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:312)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2852)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2689)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2313)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6438)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:795)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:598)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:567)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:781)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: where is this line HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)?

Comment: listView.removeFooterView(footer); is show the   // Footer (off-limits positions will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException)
        return mFooterViewInfos.get(adjPosition - adapterCount).isSelectable; But not in my code any where .I just click on that  at  lerror line in logcat  android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164) and it goes to that headerViewListAdapter.java class

Answer (score 1):

you can remove like this

> to hide Footer again at anytime use this

```
footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

> to show Footer again at anytime use this

```
footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Right now its work properly. Many many thanks.